# golang common structs in different namespaces

Tags: xml, go, xsd, code-generation, codegen

I have 160+ .xsd schemas and for each file I generated xsd.go files with [xsdgen](https://pkg.go.dev/aqwari.net/xml/cmd/xsdgen), but each document has common Header of CommonType.

```
namespace some_document

type Document struct {
    Header CommonType `xml:"header"`
        // Other fields
}


type CommonType struct {
    A  A `xml:"a"`
    B  B `xml:"b"`
    C1 C `xml:"c1"`
    C2 C `xml:"c2"`
    D  D `xml:"d"`
}

type A string

type B string

type C string

type D string
```

```
namespace any_document

type Document struct {
    Header CommonType `xml:"header"`
        // Other fields
}


type CommonType struct {
    A  A `xml:"a"`
    B  B `xml:"b"`
    C1 C `xml:"c1"`
    C2 C `xml:"c2"`
    D  D `xml:"d"`
}

type A string

type B string

type C string

type D string
```

Also, for each schema I create a function for building it. I want to create a function BuildHeader and reuse it in builder's functions. Is there any way to create common namespace with this type and use it instead any_document.CommonType and some_document.CommonType? I don't want to edit code generated files.

```
namespace common

type CommonType struct {
    A  A `xml:"a"`
    B  B `xml:"b"`
    C1 C `xml:"c1"`
    C2 C `xml:"c2"`
    D  D `xml:"d"`
}

type A string

type B string

type C string

type D string
```

My thoughts:

1. extract Header in package 'common' and change CommonType to common.CommonType for each document
2. ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with generated structures, there is no easy way of doing this. You can, however, write one function to initialize the common header and use it for all generated types, provided they are structurally identical.

```
package initializer

type CommonType struct {
  // Identical fields of the common type in all the packages
...
}

func NewCommonType() CommonType {
   // initialize an instance of CommonType
   return commonType
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var doc1 pkg1.Document
var doc2 pkg2.Document
...
doc1.CommonType = pkg1.CommonType(initializers.NewCommonType())
doc2.CommonType = pkg2.CommonType(initializers.NewCommonType())
```

Comment: The compiler says 
Cannot convert an expression of the type 'initializer.CommonType' to the type 'pkg1.CommonType

Comment: It does not work, because A B C D types in pkg1 and pkg2 are declared as well and type convertion is not transitive.

Your idea will work only if we have CommonType declared like this

`
type CommonType struct {
    A  string `xml:"a"`
    B  string `xml:"b"`
    C1 string `xml:"c1"`
    C2 string `xml:"c2"`
    D  string `xml:"d"`
}
`

Comment: Yes, CommonType must be declared identical to the common types in each package. You can copy from one type to another if they structurally match

Comment: But that means I should edit code generated code

Comment: No. You said `CommonType` is identical in each package. You declare one more, identical to those, in a new package, and write the initializer for that type. Then you can copy the initialized value to the instances of all other `CommonType`s.

Comment: It works if CommonType.A is string, not type A. Otherwise I should convert myself initializer.A to pk1.A because type convertion (casting) is not recursive in golang.

Comment: That is correct. Since each of A, B, .. are different types, different instances of `CommonType` are no longer equivalent.

Comment: So only way to use initializer is to change A,B, ... to string in codegenerated files...

Comment: You can do that. If you can get the generator generate setter methods for those fields, you can also write a generic function to initialize them.